# How to get position from string of .getSelectedItem()

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

If `ArrayAdapter<String>`, `deliveryStaffResultAdapter.getPosition(myData)` is ok. But if `CustomSpinnerAdapter`, how to get `myData` from `deliveryStaffResultAdapter`?

```
String myData = spn_staff_list.getSelectedItem().toString();
int position = deliveryStaffResultAdapter.getPosition(myData); // error here (getPosition)
```

Comment: Please post the error log.

Comment: Isn't `getPosition()` deprecated?

Comment: you can use 

spinner object  getSelectedItemPosition()

Comment: Could you please provide some more code and the error log as @cherry-wave has asked - then we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: I would guess your CustomSpinnerAdapter is not implemented correctly.  Make sure you are either calling super in the constructor and passing the array up or override the getPosition() to return the correct object.  Posting the custom adapter would help.

Answer (score 1):

`getPosition()` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getPosition()).

The Android Developer's page for this (linked above) states that:

> This method is deprecated because its meaning is ambiguous due to the async handling of adapter updates. Please use `getLayoutPosition()` or `getAdapterPosition()` depending on your use case.

Alternatively, depending on your code, the second line can use the spinner object `getSelectedItemPosition()` (as suggested by Bhavesh Vadalia) - [link to documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition()). The description of this is that it will

> Return the position of the currently selected item within the adapter's data set